# JavaScript addEventListener on document.images

Tags: javascript, events

I am trying to dynamically change a picture when I click on it, via the addEventListener. I have the pictures in the documents.images array. I already have a function written to switch the images. The problem I am having is binding this in the event that I click on an image.

This is what I tried

```
document.images[i]src.addEventListener("click", MakeMove, false);
```

Comment: You're missing a "." after [i], that's probably the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to add the event to the actual image:

```
document.images[i].addEventListener("click", MakeMove, false);
```

but older browsers don't support these DOM Level 2 event handlers, so, assuming these images don't have to have multiple click handlers, consider doing

```
document.images[i].onclick = MakeMove;
```

**EDIT**

To pass a parameter to `MakeMove`, you'd set `onclick` to an anonymous function that calls `MakeMove` with whatever values you need:

```
document.images[i].onclick = function() { 
   MakeMove(12);
}
```

---

From your original code:

```
document.images[i]src
```

isn't valid, and

```
document.images[i].src
```

would be a string, to which you obviously cannot add an event handler.

Comment: +1 for including DOM 0 method. Worth mentioning that if only one listener is required, DOM 0 is probably the best because of its ubiquitous support.

Comment: @RobG - yep - and the syntax is simpler, too :)

Comment: I have one problem that I am encountering. The MakeMove function is expecting an integer parameter. That parameter would then determine what image to switch to. I believe this is the problem, and it is the reason why nothing is happening when I click on the image.

Comment: @SteffanHarris—it is a good idea to have the function work out for itself which image to display, that way it is independent of how it is called. There are a number of strategies to do that.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a syntax error.

Try:

```
document.images[i].addEventListener("click", MakeMove, false);
```

Need to add the event listener directly on the image object. Use JSLint (www.jslint.com) to make sure to avoid this mistakes in the future!

Note: This will only work in browser that support (mostly everything but IE) .addEventListner. It's better probably to use a library so you don't have to worry about this, but if you need, .attachEvent('onclick', MakeMove) will handle IE and other cases.